# Stop Task at a specific time using Quartz

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I have a problem. I want to schedule a Task every day at 3:59:30 AM and want to stop the execution at 10:01:00 PM. For the start and end time I use cron expression. (They are not the Problem here). Now I schedule a job as following:

```
SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(Bot.class)
                .withIdentity("job", "group")
                .build();

        Trigger trigger = CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("30 59 3 ? * * *").build();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

No my question is how do I stop the execution of that job at 10:01:00 PM? And does it start automatically at 4PM again?

Comment: Tasks are supposed to be launched at a given time and run until they finish by themselves. Can't you just add logic to your Task so it checks the time and stops itself if it's past 10:01 PM?

Comment: Well I guess this thought would be to easy :D. Thanks for the mind support. The while loop inside the task now checks if the time is past 10:01 :)